# CSP blocked frame not working on smartphone

Tags: iframe, content-security-policy

I have an iFrame which I only wanted to be embeddable on a specific website. For this I found the the following code

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy: "frame-ancestors https://..."
```

I put this code into my .htaccess file and it worked perfectly when testing it on my laptop. But when I access the specific URL where the iFrame should be allowed to be embedded with my smartphone (Android + iOS), it's blocked. I searched some time on Google but couldn't find a hint or way to change this.

Hope you can help me out on this.

Edit:
I searched through the net and tested a lot of stuff but nothing works. My .htaccess looks like this:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy: "frame-ancestors domain1 domain2/embed.php?id=1;"
```

*domain2/embed.php?id=1* includes the videosource which I want to embed on another website. When calling this domain the video is ready to go in my browser. When I check the console on MAC (this seems to be a Safari problem) I get the following error message:

> The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' contains a source with invalid path: '/embed.php?id=1'. The query component, including the "?" will be ignored.
> Refused to load domain2/embed.php?id=1 because it does not appear in the frame-ancestors directive of the Content Security Policy.

When inserting https://domain2 or domain2 in the frame-ancestors line nothing changes, the video is still not available in Safari. I read that I have to insert the link in the error message to the frame-ancestors but then the ? will be ignored and the video can't be displayed.

There must be someone who has a suggestion to this problem or?

Comment: Does nobody have an answer?

Comment: Update readable in the Edit.